# Glitches in Chrome Browser in Android Emulator [Windows 11 Visual Studio 2022]

Tags: xamarin.android, android-emulator, visual-studio-2022, windows-11

When I open chrome on emulator & browse any website, I get this:

[image: Issue]

**Specifications:**

- **OS** : Windows 11 Pro
- **Processor** : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz   2.00 GHz
- **GPU** : AMD Radeon RX 550
- **Android SDK Version** : 30.8.4
- **IDE** : Visual Studio 2022
- **Emulator Specification** : Below image

[image: Android Device Manager configuration]

It was working fine on Windows 10 & Visual studio 2019.

Comment: do you have all the updates downloaded for android sdk and android studio ?

Comment: Why is the “xamarin.forms” tag on your question?

Comment: @MicahArmantrout, Everything is up to date and we are using visual studio 2022

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, I removed "xamarin.forms" tag. I gave that tag to get any one who is using xamarin forms has similar issue.

Comment: I see your point. Because its happening in the emulator, which is probably only used by people programming for Xamarin. I was just confused because it didn’t seem to have anything to do with Xamarin. I’ll add xamarin.android tag to it - that may attract those who are specifically knowledgeable about android.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It could possibly be due to the new GPU driver updates that came along for Windows 11. As a workaroud give this a try until future updates fixes it.

[image]

Choose ANGLE(D3D11) as the renderer. Find this under Settings of the Android Emulator.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After setting it to ANGLE (D3D11), as explained by Zammil, kill the emulator and start it again (in case you are wondering why it does not work). Open GL API level should stay as it is, here the image:
[image]