# Glitched screen in Android Studio emulator in Chrome browser (Windows 11)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-chrome, emulation

I'm doing some programming in Android Studio and whenever I try to load a webpage in the emulator on Chrome, I get this:

[image: glitched screen in android studio chrome]

I'm using Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1, with the emulator running a Pixel 6 on API 33, on a PC running Windows 11 Home version 21H2. If any additional information is needed to diagnose this issue, let me know.

Comment: delete this emulator and reinstall or clear storage of the emulator.

Comment: Same trouble. Win 11 too. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70023593/2628669) helped me.

Emulator **Settings** -> **Advanced** -> **OpenGL ES Renderer**: select **ANGLE (D3D11)** -> restart emulator

[image]